# Split values and renaming the columns with splitted value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

So now I have a csv and the data look like this

```
 email='abc@cde.com' AID=100200 PID=2500 NID=3950 
 email='def@ghk.com' AID=357156 PID=3544 NID=2688 
 email='testing@edu.uk' AID=385746 PID=6709 NID=2433
 ....
```

I want to split this series into a dataframe and the final table shd be as follows:

```
     email           AID     PID     NID
   abc@cde.com     100200   2500   3950
   def@ghk.com     357156   3544   2688
   testing@edu.uk  385746   6709   2433
```

In other words, what I want are as follows:

- First split the series into 4, with the delimiter ' '
- Then further split all the series in the new dataframe with the delimiter '='
- Finally form the table. The first part shd be the column name, and the sceond part shd remain as values

What I did was:

```
# Assume the df as newdf 
import pandas as pd

excel_test = pd.read_csv('filename')
newdf = excel_test.iloc[:,1].str.split(' ', expand=True)

for x in range(1, len(newdf.columns) -1):
    newdf.iloc[:,x] = newdf.iloc[:,x].str.split('=', expand=True)[1]
    new_column_name = newdf.iloc[:,x].str.split('=', expand=True)[0]
    newdf.rename(columns={newdf.columns[x]: new_column_name}, inplace=True)

print(newdf)
```

In this script, I got the values, however, I got an error:
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

When I tried to change the column name as well

So here comes to the question:

1. How can I change the column name at the same time in this case?
2. I have a feeling that the for loop can be replaced with sth like str function, in order to make the code more clean and structured. Is there any alternative way to do so?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Idea is working with column `col` with list and dictionary comprehension and split values by whitespaces by `split()` and by `=` by `split('=')`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename', names=['col'])

print (df)
                                                 col
0   email='abc@cde.com' AID=100200 PID=2500 NID=3950
1   email='def@ghk.com' AID=357156 PID=3544 NID=2688
2  email='testing@edu.uk' AID=385746 PID=6709 NID...


df = pd.DataFrame([dict(y.split('=') for y in x.split()) for x in df['col']])
print (df)
              email     AID   PID   NID
0     'abc@cde.com'  100200  2500  3950
1     'def@ghk.com'  357156  3544  2688
2  'testing@edu.uk'  385746  6709  2433
```

Another idea is use `\s+|=` separator for split by whitespace or `=` first:

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename', sep="\s+|=", header=None, engine='python')
    
print (df)
       0                 1    2       3    4     5    6     7
0  email     'abc@cde.com'  AID  100200  PID  2500  NID  3950
1  email     'def@ghk.com'  AID  357156  PID  3544  NID  2688
2  email  'testing@edu.uk'  AID  385746  PID  6709  NID  2433
```

And then select pairs columns and set columns names by unpair first row:

```
cols = df.iloc[0, ::2]
df = df.iloc[:, 1::2]
df.columns = cols
print (df)
0             email     AID   PID   NID
0     'abc@cde.com'  100200  2500  3950
1     'def@ghk.com'  357156  3544  2688
2  'testing@edu.uk'  385746  6709  2433
```

Last like mentioned @Suhas Mucherla (thank you) is possible remove `''` by [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
df['email']=df['email'].str.strip("'")
```

Comment: Awesome! Also,The email column should be stripped for `'`

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
df=pd.read_csv("/home/neureol/test2.csv",delimiter=' ',header=None).dropna(axis=1)
df.columns=[str(i).split('=')[0] for i in df.loc[0,:]]
df=df.replace('|'.join(df.columns+"="),'',regex=True)
df['email']=df['email'].str.strip("'")

df
Out[47]: 
            email     AID   PID   NID
0     abc@cde.com  100200  2500  3950
1     def@ghk.com  357156  3544  2688
2  testing@edu.uk  385746  6709  2433
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv("data.csv",delimiter=' ',header=None).dropna(axis=1)

dict1 = {}
for row in df.values.tolist():
    for item in row:
        _row = item.replace("'","").split("=")
        if _row[0] not in dict1.keys():
            dict1[_row[0]] = [_row[1]]
        else:
            dict1[_row[0]] = dict1[_row[0]] + [_row[1]]

df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
print(df)
```